# Locked myself out of WordPress because I changed my URL and computer shut down

Tags: urls

I have word press deployed on Google Cloud Platform.  I have a domain too from Google.

My IP Address for domain is is `35.243.142.95` and this is how I have it setup in WordPress. I don't know why it’s not letting me back in `http://35.243.142.95/wp-admin`.

Maybe I didn't setup the domain correctly?  I put the site URL and the URL underneath it the same.

Comment: I don't know GCP - is it VM hosting you can SSH into? You need to make sure that the web server (Apache or NGINX probably) is running (and set to automatically restart on reboot), and that it's permitted through any server and server group firewalls that you might have in the environment.

Comment: GCP support would be a good option to consider.